# In WIndows API, under what "event" do I put child control creation or why aren't my controls appearing?

Tags: c, winapi

It's been years since I last worked with Windows API and I'm trying my hand at it again.  I have a simple Window (with title "Test").  I put in the Window message handler under WM_CREATE, 2 CreateWindow calls to create a static and an edit control.  I'm pretty sure the coordinates are decent (not overlapping or off the window rectangle).  Am I putting the calls under the wrong event?  It's just a simple window - not MDI or SDI or anything like that.  Here is my code for the entire program.  I hope it's sufficient to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm using Eclipse CDT with Cygwin's G++ compiler to build it....:

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL InitApplication(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hinstance, int nCmdShow);
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

BOOL InitApplication(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = "";
    wc.lpszClassName = "MainWindow";

    return(RegisterClass(&wc));
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hinstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HINSTANCE hCurInstance = hinstance;
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("MainWindow", "Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, (HWND)(NULL), (HMENU)(NULL), hCurInstance, (LPVOID)(NULL));

    if(!hWnd)
        return(FALSE);

    // Show the window and send a WM_PAINT message to the window
        // procedure.

        ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);

        return(TRUE);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow("WC_STATIC", "&Test: ", SS_LEFT | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, 10, 50, 20, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE)), (LPVOID)(NULL));
            CreateWindow("WC_EDIT", "", WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT, 60, 10, 50, 20, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE)), (LPVOID)(NULL));
            return(0);
        default:
            return(DefWindowProcA(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
        }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmd, int nCmdShow)
{
    BOOL fGotMessage;
    MSG msg;

    if(!InitApplication(hInstance))
            return(FALSE);

    if(!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
            return(FALSE);

    while(((fGotMessage = GetMessage(&msg, (HWND) NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) && (fGotMessage != -1))
        {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

    return(msg.wParam);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WM_CREATE` is the correct "event" message to create the child controls in.

You are simply using the wrong class names for the child controls.  That is why you are not seeing them.  Had you checked the result of those `CreateWindow()` calls for failures, you would have noticed that `CreateWindow()` was returning NULL, and `GetLastError()` was reporting `ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS` (1407).

You need to replace `"WC_STATIC"` with `"Static"`, and replace `"WC_EDIT"` with `"Edit"`.  Or, you can use the pre-defined `WC_STATIC` and `WC_EDIT` constants that are defined in `<commctrl.h>`.

You can also replace `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE)` with `NULL` when creating system-defined classes, as they are registered globally, not per-module.  The `HINSTANCE` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()` is ignored for them.

---

On a side note: your `GetMessage()` loop can be simplified to just:

`while (GetMessage(&msg, (HWND) NULL, 0, 0))`

See: [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873)

Comment: Also OP is passing `(HINSTANCE)(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE))` for the `hInstance` parameter, which IIRC is used for name-scoping the class name.  OS-standard control classes won't be found in the scope of the application.

Comment: @BenVoigt "*OS-standard control classes won't be found in the scope of the application*" - actually, USER32 classes are registered globally, so it is OK to specify any `HINSTANCE` when creating them, the `HINSTANCE` will be ignored. See [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873)

Comment: Ok, I still say that particular argument value is far too ugly a snippet of code and should be deleted forthwith, particularly because it doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: You rock!  I didn't know that WC_STATIC was a constant and not a literal.  It was always in quotes on the documentation so I thought it was a literal.  My QT Creator "broke" - keeps saying it can't find a kit anymore even starting a new project so I figured maybe I'll do it with WIndows API and now I can do more programming with that.  This is awesome!  :-D  I clicked it as a selected answer!